# Where to install livy or spark job server in cloudera setup

Tags: apache-spark

Our Analytics setup is as : cloudera setup is present in a unix server. Our web application will make a rest call to big data platform ( our web is in a private cloud, the ssh is not allowed from my cloud).
I need to make a rest api request from web to the spark server(which is part of cloudera setup)
Hence we have decided to use livy or spark job server. Now i need to know
Where we have to install the livy or spark job server ...is it has to be installed in the datanode or in case of yarn do i need to install it where the resource manager is installed or can we install it in a altogether different unix box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now i need to know Where we have to install the livy or spark job server ...is it has to be installed in the datanode or in case of yarn do i need to install it where the resource manager is installed or can we install it in a altogether different unix box.

They are just another piece of software so you can install them in any server i.e. where the spark cluster is installed or any server within network. The job of these job server is to submit your job to spark.

Answer (score 1):

you can install livy on any server that is part of your hadoop cluster.
the server doesn't have to be a datanode, you can add it as a gateway to the cluster.

a gateway node, is a server that is within the network of the cluster, can also acts as a gateway to external services to access the cluster.
you can find more info on how to set up a gateway node here: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-3-x/topics/cdh_sg_gateway_setup.html

Comment: what about outside the cluster but within the network ?  can i use this configuration ...?